# Confidence interval for the ratio of Poisson to normal variables

Tags: normal-distribution, confidence-interval, poisson-distribution

In an experiment, I'm counting failures on an semiconductor device for a given fluence (i.e. amount) of neutron radiation. The failures occur according to a Poisson law.

The fluence is provided by the neutron facility. The fluence standard error $\Delta{x} = \frac{\text{s}}{\sqrt{n}}$ has been computed by the neutron facility during a beam calibration phase. $\text{s}$ is the sample standard deviation and $\text{n}$ (which I do not know) the number of calibration measurements done by the facility. We assume that the distribution of the measurements is normal.

I would like to compute the 95% confidence interval for the failure rate $F$ which is the ratio of the number of failures over this fluence: $F = \text{number failures} / \text{fluence}$

When I disregarded the uncertainty on the fluence, I used the $\chi^2$ 95% bounds to provide lower and upper limits for the number of failures; but I'd like to integrate the uncertainty on the fluence as well.

As an example, I could have 2 failures for a fluence of 1.2E6 neutrons. The fluence relative uncertainty ($\frac{\Delta{x}}{\bar{x}}$,computed from the standard error defined above) is given at 8% for this specific facility. What would be the 95% confidence interval for $F = 2 / 1.2\text{E}6$ ?

Comment: What would the standard deviation of the fluence be?  Without that, there's no way to calculate the confidence interval as you wish to.

Comment: @jbowman Sorry for the lack of clarity. I've editted the problem definition and tried to use more adequate terms.

Comment: I've puzzled over this for since you first posted, and I am still not sure what's going on here. A confidence interval would normally be for some fixed population quantity. F appears to be a random variable - do you want a prediction interval for the outcomes of $F$, or a CI for the mean of $F$, or something else?

Comment: @Glen_b I'm looking for a CI for the mean of $\text{F}$